# How do i use Zxing.net to read QrCode with mobile camera?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, zxing, nuget-package

This is the first time i'm using Zxing.net, and i want to use it with ASP.net, my website is responsive and works on mobile, and i want the user to scan the Qr Code with the mobile Camera, is there a way to do this with Vb.Net or C#?

PS : I found a way for coding and decoding the Qr code [Here](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-generate-and-read-qr-code-in-asp-net/), but i dont know how to decode it with camera scan.

Comment: Is there a way to do so or not ?, if not please let me know so i would move on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke smartphone camera in HTML5, you can try the following steps:

1. Learn how to use **getUserMedia()** to capture video in HTML5. Please refer to [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).
2. Use **XMLHttpRequest** or **WebSocket** to asynchronously send canvas data to IIS server in real-time. Please refer to [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to learn how to convert the image data. You can also read the article [How to Upload HTML Canvas Data to PHP Server](http://www.codepool.biz/upload-html-canvas-data-to-php-server.html) to learn how to send canvas data.
3. Decode the image data on the server side with ZXing.net.
4. Return the QR code result back to Web client.